# Figuring out how TradingView calculates the Sharpe ratio

Tags: returns, backtesting, sharpe-ratio, standard-deviation

This is the simplest backtest I've come up with, yet I can't figure out how TradingView has calculated the Sharpe ratio to be 0.577. I've set the risk_free_rate=0. Is it possible to extract the formula that TradingView is using from this simple example, or more data is needed?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000681694-performance-summary-sharpe-ratio/#:~:text=The%20formula%20for%20the%20Sharpe,by%20default%2C%202%25%20annually.

Comment: Yes, and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, it requires at least 3 periods.

Given the output shows 1% profit you get the following in Python,

```
# define return vector
ret = [0.01,0,0]
# compute SR 
round(np.mean(ret)/np.std(ret,ddof=1),3)
```

which yields 0.577

I voted to close this question because it is off topic here. It's probably suited for money stack exchange but it is not a quantitative finance question.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the difference between sample and population standard deviation, and didn't think of adding a null trade.

 Now there's another problem: When I have three identical trades with ret = [0.0164, 0.0164, 0.0164], I expect the Sharpe ratio to be N/A or infinity. However, TradingView shows 0.369. What kind of standard deviation could they possibly be using?

Comment: Wondering why it is off-topic. The question is relevant and I'm stuck too trying to figure out the TV Sharpe ratio formula.

Comment: I explained it in my answer. You can see what is on topic [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This site is intended for professionals and academics. The link also explains that Basic Finance and Definitions are better suited for [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/).